# I converted an integer to a string but am getting an error when try to access individual characters in that string

Tags: c#, string, integer

I am getting this error 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only. I looked for other examples of this error but unfortunately cannot find an answer.

```
 int Input = 02049256;

        string s = Input.ToString();
        int bitvalue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {                
            if (s[i] = "1")
            {
                bitvalue = column + bitvalue; 
            }
            Convert = bitvalue + Convert;
        }
```

Comment: Use s.Length instead of i < 8 because you lost the 0:  int Input = 02049256 == 2049256 ! Please never assume the length of a collection using a literal fixed value...

Comment: you have a typo  if (s[i] = "1"), should be if (s[i] == "1")

Comment: now that the error/typo was found, a few words to the error message. It tells you that strings are imutable. That means they cannot be changed. Just to understand what the compiler is talking about. ;)

Comment: @MongZhu I agree to some extent about `stings are immutable that means they cannot be changed`, you technically can with reflection if you really wanted to, but strongly discourage that.

Comment: @zaggler technically speaking yes :) but in this case the compiler has the techniques to forbid the manipulation ;)

Comment: @MongZhu yes :)

Comment: @Serge "should be if (s[i] == "1") " unfortunately this will not compile. `s[i]` returns a char. it should be `if (s[i] == '1')`

Comment: @MongZhu Thank you. you are right but compiller would give  another error in this case too. It  was just my typo, but in any case it was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You don't compare, you assign inside your if statement (**Update**: as suggested in comments, you also need to change "1" string to '1' char)

instead of

```
if (s[i] = "1")
```

use

```
if (s[i] == '1')
```

Also, you start your int value with 0, which won't be included in the string

Comment: unfortunately this will not compile. s[i] returns a char. it should be if (s[i] == '1')

Comment: @MongZhu you're right, I'll change it

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I made a mistake. It is not a string but a char that you are comparing. So you need to use `s[i] == '1'`

For comparing an entry of an array to a string, you need to use the `==` operator and not the `=` operator. The operator `=` reassigns your entry in this case, which means that the value of `s[i]` has become "1". And it's also always good to use `.Equals` when comparing strings. So in your case: `if (s[i].Equals("1"))`

Comment: unfortunately the method equals can be a pain ;) actually it compares instances, so in this use case that you posted it will return false. you can try it yourself: `string s = "asd"; Console.WriteLine($"Equals: {s[1].Equals("s")}");`

Comment: actually you ran into a trap there. `s[1]` will return a `char`. If you would compare it with a char: `s[1].Equals('s')` it would take the correct overload and return true. But! If you put a string into equals, then it will take the inherited overload from the object class which takes a `object` as input parameter and compares the instances! this is why it will return false. You really should either change or remove this part from your answer

Comment: Ah true! I totally oversaw that. Thanks!